# Create a JSON object with variables as fields

Tags: javascript, json

I want to create a JSON object with variables as associative variable names similar to the following:

```
var field = 'first';
var query = { details.field, details.field };
```

I would prefer if the details were a fixed value.

This is my dataset currently

```
{
    field1: ,
    group: {
        first:
    }
}
```

My question is, how would I go about creating JSON objects with variables as fields?

Answer (score 2):

You can add a property to an object like so:

```
var query = { details: {} };
var field = 'first';

query.details[field] = "TEST";
```

Which will give you the object:

```
{ details: { first: "TEST" }}
```

which you can then access with query.details.first or query.details[field];

Is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to accomplish this in Javascript is using the . operator.

```
query.details.field = "first";
```

This will product an object as follows:

```
"query" { "details" { "field": "first"} }
```

Is this what your looking for?

If you want multiple details you will want to use an array.

```
var query = [];
query.push({"details" { "field" : "first"} });
query.push({"details" { "field" : "second"} });
```

This will product an object like this
    "query" [
        "details" { "field" : "first"},
        "details" { "field" : "second"}
    ]